# jQuery: How to Scroll to an Element, which was enlarged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I got a rather annoying Problem:
On my Website, there are some covers of CDs. I'm able to enlarge the covers via jQuery.switchClass.

Now I'd like to jump to the enlarged cover. But I don't get how.

Here's the Link to the Website: http://53333805.swh.strato-hosting.eu/reinhold/alt_2/disko.php

Here's the code:

```
<script>                    
$(function() {
  $("a.cd").click(function(event) {    
     $( ".cd-klein" ).switchClass( "cd-klein", "cd-gross", 1200, "easeInOutQuint" );
     $( ".cd-beschreibung" ).toggleClass( "cd-da", 700);
     $( ".cd-gross" ).switchClass( "cd-gross", "cd-klein", 1200, "easeInOutQuint" );
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

An the HTML-Markup:

```
<!--CD 1-->
    <a class="cd" href="#1">
     <div class="cd-beschreibung">
        <div class="cd-name">Reinhold Friedrich</div>
          <div class="cd-besetzung">
            großes Kammerorchester<br />
     <br />
            Leitung: Claudio Abbado
          </div>
            <div class="cd-kaufen">hier zu kaufen</div>
            <div class="clear-right"></div>
        </div>
     <img id="1" class="cd-klein" src="images/disko/beispiel1.jpg">
    </a>
```

The other CDs a similar to the "CD1".

Thanks for any help!

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, but I'm not sure will it work:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.cd").click(function(event) {    
    var eq = $('.cd img').index(this);
    $( ".cd-klein" ).switchClass( "cd-klein", "cd-gross", 1200, "easeInOutQuint", function() {
      $('.text').get(0).scrollTop = 80 + eq * 219;
    } );
    $( ".cd-beschreibung" ).toggleClass( "cd-da", 700);
    $( ".cd-gross" ).switchClass( "cd-gross", "cd-klein", 1200, "easeInOutQuint" );
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
But unfortunately it doesn't scroll. I don't get, why the scroll-function doesn't work at all. Even if I just put this function in my code...

Answer (score 0):

try placing

```
<script>                    
$(function() {
  $("a.cd").click(function(event) {    
     $( ".cd-klein" ).switchClass( "cd-klein", "cd-gross", 1200, "easeInOutQuint" );
     $( ".cd-beschreibung" ).toggleClass( "cd-da", 700);
     $( ".cd-gross" ).switchClass( "cd-gross", "cd-klein", 1200, "easeInOutQuint" );

     $(this).animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, "slow");
   return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work either. 
I haven't thought, that this could be this hard, to scroll to an element.

It's possible to get the number of the clicked element. Is there a possibility to get the scroll-function to take that number and scroll to it?!

If anyone got any ideas, I would be so glad :)